# List function in XPages

Tags: javascript, list, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to use the same function in XPages via Javascript.

```
Dim firstList List As Double
Dim secondList List As Double 

firstList("any")= 0 
firstList("many")= 2 
firstList("work")= 23
```

Any suggestion is appreciated. 
 Regards
Cumhur Ata

Comment: Is this for client-side JS or server-side JS?

Comment: It's for Server Side JavaScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a JavaScript [object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp):

Initialize object with

```
var firstList = {any:0, many:2, work:23};
```

or

```
var firstList = {};
firstList.any = 0;
firstList.many = 2;
firstList["work"] = 23;
```

Get an entry value with

```
var anyNumber = firstList.any;
var manyNumber = firstList["many"];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this in server-side JavaScript you can use a HashMap and do something like this:

```
var firstList = new java.util.HashMap();
firstList.put("any", 0 );
firstList.put("many", 2);
firstList.put("work", 23);
```

You can then use firstList.get(key) to get the value.

Comment: Bear in mind that LS Lists only use strings for key, so List("2") is the same as List(2). Java will treat the two keys as different.

Comment: Not sure if you can decalre type safe variables in SSJS but if so, your should do:
var firstList = new java.util.HashMap<String, Integer>();